# sort a list which contains alphnumerical values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list called

```
my_list=['C3', 'D10', 'A14', 'C103', 'B16', 'C9','AD24']
```

I would like to sort this list and have an output like

```
my_list=['A14', 'AD24', 'B16', 'C3', 'C9', 'C103', 'D10']
```

I am not sure what logic i need to implement in my key function.

```
def my_func(x):                                                                   
    result = ''                                                                   
    my_str = ''.join([str(ord(elem)) if elem.isalpha() else elem for elem in x])  
    for elem in my_str:                                                           
        result += elem                                                            
    return result
```

And then when i try this I am not getting the desired output.

```
sorted(my_list, key=my_func)               
['A14', 'AD24', 'B16', 'C103', 'C3', 'C9', 'D10']
```

Any ideas where i am going wrong?

Comment: would there be only a single character at the beginning or is it variable?

Comment: There could be a variable number of characters like BB2027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

my_list=['C3', 'D10', 'A14', 'C103', 'B16', 'C9']

a = re.compile('([0-9]+)')

def sort(b):
    return [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
            for text in re.split(a, b)]

my_list.sort(key=sort)
print (my_list)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
['A14', 'B16', 'C3', 'C9', 'C103', 'D10']
```

I think this might work. This is natural sort, I had this somewhere in my practice code files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `natsort` module like that

```
from natsort import natsorted, ns
x = ['C3', 'D10', 'A14', 'C103', 'B16', 'C9','AD24']
y = natsorted(x, alg=ns.IGNORECASE)
print(y)
```

Will output:

```
['A14', 'AD24', 'B16', 'C3', 'C9', 'C103', 'D10']
```